# Compute $\inf_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}\int_{|x-y|<1}\frac{dy}{|y|^{n-\lambda}}$ where $0<\lambda<n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $0<\lambda<n$ and consider the integral
$$f(x):=\int_{|x-y|<1}\frac{dy}{|y|^{n-\lambda}}.$$

Since $|y|^{-n+\lambda}$ is locally integrable, the function $f$ is continuous.

Is it possible to find  $\inf_{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}}f(x)$ ?

One can compute $f(x)$ explicitly in the one-dimensional case.  So the question is about dimensions $n\geq 2$.

We also know that
$$f(0)=\int_{B(1)}\frac{dy}{|y|^{n-\lambda}}=\frac{|\mathbb{S}^{n-1}|}{\lambda}$$
by means of spherical coordinates.

Using spherical coordinates we can write
$$f(x):=\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}\int_{|x|^2-2r\omega\cdot x +r^2<1}r^{\lambda-1} dr d\sigma(\omega).$$

I am stuck here. One idea is to look for critical points, but I don't know if $f$ is differentiable and I don't know how to compute a partial derivative of $f$ either!

Comment: Do you need to calculate $f$ directly? Because the infimum is zero, for any $\varepsilon>0$, if $x$ is large enough, the integrant is smaller than $\varepsilon$. If this is enough for you I can add it as an answer with more details.

Comment: Yes, It would be great of you give a precise  account of the asymptotic behaviour of $f(x)$ as $|x|\rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, if $|x|$ is large, and $|x-y|<1$, ie $y\in B^n(x,1)$, then $|y|$ is also large. So for any $\varepsilon>0$, $f(x)<\varepsilon$ if $|x|$ is large enough, and since $f(x)>0$, we have $\inf_{x\in\mathbb R^n} f(x) =0$.

Making it more precise, since $|x-y|<1$ we have $|y|>|x|-1$ from the triangle inequality. Thus $\frac{1}{|y|^{n-\lambda}}<\frac{1}{||x|-1|^{n-\lambda}}<\varepsilon$ if $|x| - 1 > \varepsilon^{-1/(n-\lambda)}$.

So for a fixed $\varepsilon>0$ we choose $x$ large enough, as above, so that $|y|^{-\lambda + n}<\varepsilon$. Then $f(x)< \int_{|x-y|<1} \varepsilon dy = \varepsilon|B^n(x,1)| = \varepsilon|B^n(0,1)|$.

We can take this a step further, $|y|<|x|+1<2|x|$ for $|x|$ large, and similarly $|y|>|x|-1|>|x|/2$. So
$$2^{\lambda-n}|x|^{\lambda-n}|B^n(0,1)| < f(x)< 2^{n-\lambda}|x|^{\lambda-n}|B^n(0,1)|$$
when $|x|$ is large.